# Pyrocms : blank page on database load

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, pyrocms

I have a website running with Pyrocms & CodeIgniter.

My config is the following:
Debian: 5.0.9
Apache: 2.2.9
MySQL: 5.0.51
PHP: 5.2.6-1

I'm facing the following problem:

I receive POST requests to insert messages in my database.
Sometimes the frequency of db insert is up to 100 messages / seconds

Database engine used : innoDD

After a moment I get a white page when i try to reach the homepage or any modules except the admin.

www.project.com is giving HTTP status 200 but page is blank
same for www.project.com/mycontroller is giving HTTP status 200 but page is blank
admin is working fine

In my log files i have following errors :
ERROR - 2011-11-18 15:04:28 --> Severity: Notice  --> iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string /home/project/system/codeigniter/core/Utf8.php 89

For the moment i do a dump of my db every 30 minutes and rollback to the last working db when the plateform is crashing.

I have made some tests on my database with mysqlcheck but everything seems to be ok in the db.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your database all UTF8 Unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is probably choking on some characters when converting with iconv. try adding "//IGNORE" to you second argument so it looks something like that

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text);
```